# What is a sequence of partition for integration?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently reading a chapter on integration in a real analysis textbook and there is a corollary of the cauchy criterion of integration. Now they define the cauchy criterion for integration as: there exist a partition where the difference of the upper and lower sum is less than epsilon.

Now for this corollary, it is stated that there exist a sequence of partitions Pn where the limit as n approaches infinity difference between the upper sum and lower sum is 0.

So my question is what exactly is a sequence of partitions ?

Comment: Infinitely many partitions of the interval. SORRY. Countably many.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: countably many, no ?

Comment: is there an example of a sequence of partition?

Comment: It is essentially letting the number of subintervals in the partition $P_n$ become arbitrarily large, which means each successive $P_{n+1}$ is a refinement of $P_n$, so that $U(f,P_{n+1})\leq U(f,P_n)$ and $L(f,P_{n+1})\geq L(f,P_n)$. Both of these will converge to the true value of the integral and one can show that these definitions, Cauchy and the sequential definition, are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

One example of a sequence of partitions $(P_k)_{k \geq 0}$ for the interval $[0,1]$ is the following.

$$P_0 = \{[0,1]\}$$

$$P_1 = \{[0,1/2), [1/2,1]\}$$

$$P_2 = \{[0,1/4), [1/4,1/2), [1/2,3/4), [3/4,1]\}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$P_k = \{[i/2^k, i+1/2^k), [(2^k-1)/2^k,1] : 0 \leq i \leq 2^k-2\}$$

$$\vdots$$

and so each $P_k$ is a partition of $[0,1]$ and as $k$ increases, we (in this case) get a finer and finer partition.

Hopefully that helps.