# What is a sequence of partitions in integration?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

Right now in my introductory real analysis course, we are studying integration theory, and in particular the Archimedes-Riemann theorem. The Archimedes-Riemann theorem requires the existence of an Archimedean sequence of partitions, $\{P_n\}$, for integrability.

But what is a sequence of partitions, $\{P_n\}$? In particular, what is $P_i$? This is never clarified in the book. My intuition, however, based on all of the limits involving ${P_n}$, is that $i$ corresponds in some way with the number of partitions, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $P_n$ gets finer and finer.

Is this correct?

Comment: There is a question with EXACTLY(a.e.) the same title: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895028/what-is-a-sequence-of-partition-for-integration.

I copy my comment there: A sequen ce of partitions is a set of countably many partitions of the interval.

Comment: What is a sequence of elements of a set $X$? It's a function from $\Bbb N$ into $X$. In this case, $X$ is the set of all partitions of $[a,b]$.